# Split records into multiple rows based on range provided in column using sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I am looking to Split records into multiple rows based on range provided in column using sql server. Please provide help.

Sample Source Data  set as below -

```
account_no    range
abc_111       2001…2010
```

Expected Target data set as below -

```
account_no         range
abc_111             2001
abc_111             2002
abc_111             2003
abc_111             2004
abc_111             2005
abc_111             2006
abc_111             2007
abc_111             2008
abc_111             2009
abc_111             2010
```

Also, Source and expected Target data shown in attached picture.

Comment: Another example - 
Source Data Set 

Account_no          Range
abc                 2001...2010
xyz          301...315
xyz      401...403


Expected Target Data Set


Account_no         Range
abc                2001
abc                2002
abc                2003
abc                2004
abc                2005
abc                2006
abc                2007
abc                2008
abc                2009
abc                2010
xyz      301
xyz      302
xyz      303
xyz      304
xyz      305
xyz      401
xyz      402
xyz      403

Answer (score 0):

You need a numbers-like table to split the data.  You can construct one yourself:

```
select sd.account_no, substring_index(range, '...', 1) + n.n - 1
from sourcedata sd join
     (select 1 as n union all
      select 2 union all
      . . .
      select 10
     ) n
     on n.n >= 1 and
        n.n <= substring_index(range, '...', -1) - substring_index(range, '...', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My each account has different number of ranges. It could have any numbers e.g. 10 or 5 or 100.

Comment: Source Data Set 

Account_no          Range
abc                 2001...2010
xyz          301...315
xyz      401...403


Expected Target Data Set


Account_no         Range
abc                2001
abc                2002
abc                2003
abc                2004
abc                2005
abc                2006
abc                2007
abc                2008
abc                2009
abc                2010
xyz      301
xyz      302
xyz      303
xyz      304
xyz      305
xyz      401
xyz      402
xyz      403

Comment: @Angelia . . . You just need a large enough numbers table.